# ShapeRender issue

Tags: android, libgdx

When I use Shaperenderer, I can see what I am drawing between the shaperender block. No problem. But it is not displaying the sprite using `b.renderMap`. This is the following code:

```
b.drawBoard(batch, shapeRenderer,camera);
      batch.begin();
      b.renderMap(batch);
      batch.end();
```

Shaperendere block:

```
 shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
     shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
     shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.PINK);
     shapeRenderer.filledRect(0, 0, width, height);
     shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GRAY);
     shapeRenderer.filledRect(10, 20, width-30, height-10);
     shapeRenderer.end();
```

If I comment `shapeRenderer blo`ck , I am able to see my sprite. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's necessary to do

```
batch.end()
```

before you draw shapeRender. And do

```
batch.begin()
```

after. Maybe problem somewhere there.